# When do new faculty find out about their teaching assignment?

Tags: united-states, teaching, tenure-track

I'm joining a US university as a tenure-track assistant professor in January. I was previously told that I will teach 1 undergraduate course in the spring semester which will start in the 2nd week of January. Despite sending multiple emails, I was unable to find out *which* course I would be teaching. The only answer I got so far is that "details about the teaching assignment will be sent out in due course".

I find this a bit concerning, as I think it will be very difficult to prepare an undergraduate course in just a few weeks that I have never taught before, while moving my family (with two small kids) across the continent during the December holiday season. However, maybe this is what I should expect. Thus my question:

**How soon before the start of the term can one to expect to find out about the teaching assignment?**

Comment: I doubt that your experience is typical. It is certainly sub-optimal.

Comment: I think a more interesting question would be "How much time _should_ new faculty be given to prepare for their first classes?".

Comment: I don't suppose you could go into an online search portal and find yourself listed as teaching something?  It would be less official than your department telling you, but would give you something.  On the other hand, if they're not telling you, then it's likely that the online portal will just have a bunch of "To be determined".

Answer (score 10):

These are not normal times but you should still normally know by now.  Even if it is not yet “official”, i.e. the Dean or someone higher up has not formally assigned you course(s), the Chair should have a very good idea of what you will be teaching.

Where I work the Chair submits recommendations for teaching loads to the Dean in March for the academic year starting in September, and the Dean officially informs instructors in late June/early July.

I don’t remember when we last had a January start, and lots of people are moving (albeit not at Xmas time), so you are not unique in that, but I have a friend starting in January at another school and she was given teaching duties months ago.

Answer (score 8):

The actual answer to the question is, sadly, sometime between when it is possible and when it is convenient. But, I think that in your case it is approaching the time when it amounts to abuse (maybe too strong a word). It is possible that the administration doesn't understand the constraints of moving and such that are making the problem harder than it would be otherwise.

Most faculty (not newbies) usually know long in advance unless there are special circumstances. Some last minute changes do happen, since, for example, people leave or die. A scramble ensues. But usually the last minute changes are reasonable, as an experienced instructor can be found for that course, even someone who has taught it before in many cases. But an experienced instructor also has many tricks for ramping up a course quickly, especially if there are materials available from earlier instantiations.

It is much harder for a new, inexperienced, instructor, so they should be given longer than usual notice. For an experienced instructor, a couple of weeks is usually enough to "throw together" enough materials to get started and have an overall plan, even if some things still need development.

But, ideally, two things should happen, and they often do. First, a university does well to ease new faculty into the classroom with easier, and even lighter, assignments for a year (say). There is a lot for a tenure track professor to work in to in the first year or so. Also, ideally, such folks should be given a say in what they will teach, even if others need to yield favorite courses.

I'm assuming, of course, and hopefully not in vain, that people like department heads and deans really want the educational process to be done well and for new faculty to become productive in a *mutually beneficial* way. I worry that this is being neglected in your case.

However, as soon as you know what you are to teach (and accept it), try to get, from other faculty, any materials they have on the course, assuming it is regularly given. Consult with anyone available to get their sense of how to make it work. Don't neglect that the first few class sessions are important in setting the tone of a course as well as the expectations of the students.

Without all the other hassles (moving, etc) a month should be sufficient, but expect to have to lean on other people for help in this situation, both at home and at work.

Answer (score 6):

It's not at all typical, but it happens, especially in the current environment of pandemic, mask mandates, mixed online classes, and uncertainty about enrollment.

Based on my experiences, the department probably has a pretty good idea of what course(s) they want you to teach. However the schedule is not set in stone until almost the first day of classes. E.g., there is a chance that some other course taught by someone more senior will be cancelled because of low enrollement, and that person might get "your" course instead, and you'll get "bumped" to some other course. On the totem pole, you're above the adjuncts, but below most full-time people. Or, e.g., it's possible that the course you're now penciled in for won't run, and you'll be given some oher course, perhaps "bumping" an adjunct.

The department probably has a pretty good idea of its second choice for your course might be. However they don't really know you yet, and, I'm guessing, perhaps based on their past bad experiences with other people, are afraid that if they give you too much information in writing, you will then complain (or even sue) if you end up teaching something other than what they originally planned. Perhaps next semester, after they get to know you better, they'll tell you more earlier. Or perhaps they don't tell anyone, in order to increase their flexibility to re-schedule at the last moment.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that in “normal” circumstances you know what you’re teaching well before the academic year starts, but that as soon as you’re in an “unusual” situation (eg your original class gets cancelled for under-enrollment, or your situation of getting hired mid-year) then it’s likely to get decided very last minute. The point is that you have to cover all the classes and you don’t want to re-assign someone who is already assigned a class, so you need to keep flexibility for those last few classes.

Comment: Much easier for an experienced instructor to "be flexible" than for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, my department sent around teaching assignments for most everyone last week. Mine was for a course that I suspected would not make it because of low enrollment, and we pulled the plug on it on Friday. So I only learned my real assignment on Friday December 3.

I won't say that that's "typical", but what's typical anyway these days.